# How do I trigger <Suspense> again after a useSearchParams change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

not to make things too simple, but my code goes like this -

```
const Component = () => {
    const { data } = useLoaderData();
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    const handleClick = () => {
        searchParams.set('page', parseInt(searchParams.get('page')) + 1);
        setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={ <>Loading</> }>
                <Await resolve={data}>
                    { (data) => <>data</> }
                </Await>
            </Suspense>
            <button onClick={ () => handleClick() }>Next Page</button>
        </>
    )

}
```

The suspense works when data is being fetched the first time, but I add searchParams, the data changes, but it never shows the suspense anymore. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: From what I understand that may be all that there is to it. Once the dynamically loaded data has been fetched once and the UI suspended & loaded, it's already loaded, there is nothing to suspend again. See [when does the `Suspense` fallback render?](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred#when-does-the-suspense-fallback-render) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior, the `Suspense`/`Await` only do their work on the initial render. See [When does the `<Suspense />` fallback render?](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred#when-does-the-suspense-fallback-render) for details.

> The `<Await />` component will only throw the promise up the `<Suspense>`
> boundary on the initial render of the `<Await />` component with an
> unsettled promise. It will not re-render the fallback if props change.
> Effectively, this means that you *will not* get a fallback rendered when
> a user submits a form and loader data is revalidated. You *will* get a
> fallback rendered when the user navigates to the same route with
> different params.

The route will revalidate, e.g. call the loader function, under a few cases as described by [`shouldRevalidate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate). You should be specifically interested in the search params case.

> There are several instances where data is revalidated, keeping your UI
> in sync with your data automatically:
>
> - After an action is called from a .
> - After an action is called from a <fetcher.Form>
> - After an action is called from useSubmit
> - After an action is called from a fetcher.submit
> - When the URL params change for an already rendered route
> - ***When the URL Search params change***
> - When navigating to the same URL as the current URL

You could use the [`useNavigation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation) hook in `Component` and determine if the route is loading data again and conditionally render any loading UI.

Example:

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
import {
  Await,
  useLoaderData,
  useNavigation, // <--
  useSearchParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const { data } = useLoaderData();
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // <--

  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const handleClick = () => {
    searchParams.set("page", (Number(searchParams.get("page")) ?? 0) + 1);
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<>Loading Initial Data</>}>
        <Await resolve={data}>
          {(data) =>
            navigation.state === "loading" ? ( // <--
              <>Loading New Data</>
            ) : (
              <>data: {data}</>
            )
          }
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next Page</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-trigger-suspense-again-after-a-usesearchparams-change]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. This totally works for my use case. Additionally, I appreciate you replacing the ParseInt, I didnt realize Number is a thing and is better.